# Conflicts in iml files of supported modules in android studio though I am not making any change in those modules?

Tags: android-studio

What are .iml files in android studio? Why sometimes I get conflicts in iml files of supported modules though I am not making any change in those modules?

Answer (score 0):

IML is a module file created by IntelliJ IDEA, an IDE used to develop Java applications. It stores information about a development module, which may be a Java, Plugin, Android, or Maven component; saves the module paths, dependencies, and other settings. Looking for how to open iml files? Checkout http://www.openthefile.net/extension/iml